# Porting cocos2d to Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cocos2d-iphone

Does any one know how porting is done. Actually I want to port cocos2d to Qt platform & I have no idea about this. If anyone know please help me.

Comment: I don't understand the question - cocos2d is a framework for Python, written purely in python (no native code in there at all), hence what do you mean by "port it to Qt" ?

Comment: cocos2d is designed to use for iphone & ipad only but it is ported to badaOS & Android devices. So I want to do the same for qt also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to look at is not Cocos2D itself (which is pure python and will require a platform for which Python is available, including OpenGL / SDL functionality), but rather *Cocos2D-X*. That provides a cross-platform C++ API closely mapped to Cocos2D's python interfaces.
See:

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki

and specifically for Symbian / "Qt Platform", check:

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/373

Comment: thanks for all these help  but I have already seen these pages. But i could not understand how to do that. What all files I need to change?

Comment: A very simple start would be to copy everything from e.g. `cocos2dx/platform/win32` into `cocos2dx/platform/qt` and then go through all the files in that directory, reimplementing functionality using Qt methods. The mentioned thread on the mailing list talks about this.

Comment: thanks for the help I am trying to convert the classes to Qt. let see if it works properly.

Comment: Actually there are the pretty much unknown Cocos2d, its much more famous objC variant cocos2d-iphone, which is not only a port, but also  a fork of the original cocos2d and then there is cocos2d-x which is a C++ port of cocos2d-iphone, not of cocos2d.

Answer (score 1):

Cocos2D-x already works with Marmalade, so if you want to take your Cocos2D game to iOS, Android, Symbian, webOS, bada, RIM QNX and more, check out Marmalade:
http://madewithmarmalade.com

Comment: Hey Tim! I know you're the CEO of Marmalade, but, and correct me if I'm wrong, just using Cocos2d-x in Marmalade won't give you all the platforms that Marmalade supports. You'll still only be able to target the platforms that Cocos2d-x itself supports, since it isn't using Marmalades OpenGL wrapper, Iw2d api to do graphics under the hood. Same deal with sound management, correct?

Comment: Hi Tim, I want to compile the Cocos2D-x using the Marmalade environment. But there is no tutorial, and no easy step explanation anyway that describes exactly how to do this.